# sum to zero gives 0. with ifort and 3.1225e-16 with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I would like to know if there is a specific option for gfortran so that the following sum enclosed in a loop in i

```
startx+(i-iref)*dx
```

which is

```
-15+(376-1)*0.04
```

gives 0. exactly with gfortran (as it does with ifort).

These numbers are not integers and are defined as

```
real :: dx=0.04
double precision :: iref=1.d0,startx=-15.
integer i=376 !(classic i of a loop)
```

[ifort is compiled with
       -O0 -assume byterecl -r8
while gfortran with
       -O0 -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8]

Is it possible? Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be the case for

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do... could you show us the whole loop?

Comment: Be a little careful, you seem to know that `1.d0` is a double precision real literal, but `-15.` is (compilation options aside) not.  I don't expect the difference between `-15.` and `-15.0d0` to have a material impact on your case.

Comment: With my gfortran the given flags evidently make everything double precision including the `real` declaration and the literals, and I get "exactly" zero for the shown calculation. If any of the constants were single precision you'd get a much larger O 10^-7 error.  At the end of the day if 10^-16 matters you are doing something wrong.

Comment: If you used 32-bit mode compilers, the default for gfortran is to use 80-bit extended precision format, while for ifort it is SSE2 64-bit data format.  Just an example to show the insufficiency of the problem description.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you do some arithmetics on floating point numbers, there is no/hardly ever such a thing as zero precisely. This is mainly due to the limited precision of the floating point representation.

If you want to check whether a value is zero, use something on the lines of

```
if ( abs(res) <= 1.e-5 ) then
  write(*,*) 'res=',0.e0
else
  write(*,*) 'res=',res
endif
```

(This is the single precision version. )